# How to fix "Unknown network "ganache". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks."

Tags: ethereum, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to deploy a contract to rinkeby. I'm using the following command:

```
$ truffle migrate --networks rinkeby

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Voting.sol
> Artifacts written to ./public/contracts/build/
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang

Unknown network "ganache". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.
Truffle v5.0.22 (core: 5.0.22)
Node v11.6.0
```

It works witch `ganache-cli` but it doesn't work with rinkeby, because its giving me the error of `Unknown network "ganache". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks` as showed in the result above.

This is my `truffle-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "./public/contracts/build/"),
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: 1000,
      gas: 4612388,
      gasPrice: 25000000000,
      total_accounts: 20,
      mnemonic
    },
    rinkeby: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infuraURL),
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4612388,
      gasPrice: 25000000000,
    },
  },
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having this error, my problem was that I was writting wrong the command. The correct form should be:
`truffle migrate --network rinkeby  # Network is without the 's'`

Comment: Thanks, I would have paused the job I am working on till further notice 